# How to run parallel task (scp task for multiple hosts) for list of inputs using Ant

Tags: ant

I'm trying to get like below. but its doing SCP task only to the last host in the list. please help how to do SCP to all list of inputs in parallel?

```
<for list="${scp.server}" param="tmphttpServer" trim="true" parallel="true">
  <sequential>
    <property name="httpServer" value="@{tmphttpServer}" />
    <echo>${httpServer} </echo>
    <scp todir="${scp.user.id}@${httpServer}:${scp.remote.dir}"
     port="${scp.port}"
     keyfile="${scp.keyfile}"
     passphrase="${scp.passphrase}"
     trust="${scp.trust}"
     knownhosts="${scp.knownhosts}">
      <fileset dir="${static.web.dir}">                                                                  
      </fileset>
    </scp>
    <var name="httpServer" unset="true"/>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

Comment: You can use a macrodef(like a function) to do scp which can take parameters. Then you can call host wise. You may check here for more details on macrodef http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/10/18/apache-ant-define-your-custom-ant-task-using-macrodef/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i will try the same